# Angular 2+: Best way to inject large amounts of input data into an application at init time?

Tags: angular

Imagine that you're developing a simple Angular 4 app which is *not* a SPA – it's just a widget that adds UI sugar to an HTML form. For the purposes of this question, let's say that it allows the user to edit a restaurant menu.

The usual approach, as I understand it, is this:

1. The user agent requests the URL `/menus/173/edit`, and downloads an HTML page containing a `<menu-editor menuId="173"></menu-editor>` tag, and a `<script>` tag which loads the transpiled Angular module.
2. The app initializes, binds to the DOM, and resolves the value of the `menuId` input as `173`.
3. The app then issues a second HTTP request to `/api/menus/173` to retrieve the menu details and populate the form.

I'm hoping to eliminate step 3, for the sake of load time / performance.

Is there a best practice for including the menu details in the original page load, and getting that data into my `<menu-editor></menu-editor>` component?

Of course, I could do something like this:

`<menu-editor [menuDetails]="{ id: 174, categories: [ ... ] }"></menu-editor>`

...but that feels a little wrong, somehow (especially if the JSON object is large). Is there a tried-and-true way of injecting "inline" data into an Angular 2+ app?

I understand that this approach isn't appropriate for every situation. I'm just looking for ways to improve performance in this specific case (an Angular app which simply adds a rich UI to an otherwise ordinary HTML form).

Comment: Check out Angular Universal: https://universal.angular.io/ and Angular Elements: http://nitayneeman.com/posts/building-a-custom-element-using-angular-elements/

Comment: It is easy to do with a loader.

Comment: @DeborahK: Thanks; I'll take a look at those.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Can you explain what you mean by a "loader" in this context? Do you have a link, or just a keyword I can Google? (Searching for "angular 4 loader" and the like doesn't help much.)

Comment: @greenie2600 Sorry for not being clearer, I meant a JavaScript module loader like SystemJS.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 4+ framework is not designed to cooperate in standard html application. By Angular 4+, you can write only application, no component to be used into html pages. To accomplish your task, i suggest you to use look other libraries/framework like AngularJS or JQuery.

Comment: If that is true, Angular would be at a severe disadvantage compared to AngularJS, Aurelia, and every other SPA framework. It is not true, but Angular is very uncooperative, making the task difficult. It can be done.